# MS Access Report With Multiple Records Per Page

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm fairly new to VBA programming and I'm attempting to create a report in MS Access.  However, each record in the report is printed to a new page.  How do I specify in my code that the records should all be printed on the same page and only move on to the next page when it runs out of space on the first page?  Right now I'm using a loop that prints each field from my SQL query, but each record found ends up on a separate page.

```
For Each fld In rs.Fields

    Set txtNew = CreateReportControl(rpt.Name, acTextBox, _
    acDetail, , fld.Name, lngLeft + 1500, lngTop)
    txtNew.SizeToFit

    Set lblNew = CreateReportControl(rpt.Name, acLabel, acDetail, _
    txtNew.Name, fld.Name, lngLeft, lngTop, 1400, txtNew.Height)
    lblNew.SizeToFit

    lngTop = lngTop + txtNew.Height + 25
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you use code for a report.  The report wizard will allow specifying the data elements, and layout specifications via property sheets.  When I tried with a very basic report and I was using the report wizard, it prompted me for layout style.  I selected tabular and see many rows of data on one page of the report...

[image]